# how to delete record from the listview on touch event from sqlitedatabase ,via context menu

Tags: android, sqlite, contextmenu

I want to delete data from sqlite data base . i already display records or data from sqlitedab to the listview .now i am trying to delete the  record when user click on the particular record which is displayed in list view. i uses context menu  for update and delete option when user click on particular record .my issue is that im not successfully apply delete option in that context menu and not able to delete that particular record !!

my code is below :

```
 public class update_page extends Activity 
{

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    public String tableName = db.TABLE_CONTACTS;
    public String databaseName = db.DATABASE_NAME;
    public String taskID = db.KEY_ID;

    public String task_name = db.KEY_TASK;
    public String dt = db.KEY_DATETIME;
    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> results2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent op_intent;
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    ListView myview;
    Cursor c;
    String o_name,o_no1;
    //String o_id1 = null;
     HttpClient client;
    Integer op_id,status;
    String url;
    Context ctx;
    Intent myintent;

    final MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
    protected Object adapter;

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.update_list);
            final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(update_page.this, "Please wait", "Login please wait..", true);
            myPd_ring.setCancelable(true);
            myPd_ring.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            new Thread() {

                public void run() {

                try{

                sleep(1000);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                }

                // dismiss the progress dialog

                myPd_ring.dismiss();

                }

                }.start();


            myview = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);
            ctx=this;





            database = act.getInstance().openOrCreateDatabase("contactsManager",
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);       
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database is open", 1500).show();


       //  database=this.openOrCreateDatabase("contactsManager", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);

            final String[] columnsone={"_id","task_name","date_time"};
            String[] columnstwo={"task_name","date_time"};
            int to[] = {R.id.lbl_task,R.id.lbl_datetime}; 
            c = database.query("contacts", columnsone, null, null, null, null, null);
            status=c.getCount();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "totle task :" +status, 1500).show();



             if(c!=null)
               {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in courser", 1500).show();
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new 
                        SimpleCursorAdapter(update_page.this,R.layout.update_listview, c, columnstwo, to);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "records are in list", 1500).show();

                myview.setAdapter(adapter);


                        myview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
                        {

                            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View record, int arg2, long arg3)
                            {
                                update_page.this.registerForContextMenu(record);

                                return false;
                            }

                        });
                }
             }
            //@Override 
            public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
            {
                AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
                int choice = item.getItemId();
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Task", 2000).show();

                    Intent op_intent = new Intent(update_page.this,MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    update_page.this.startActivity(op_intent);

                    break;

                case 2:



                    database = act.getInstance().openOrCreateDatabase("contactsManager",
                    SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);       
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("are you sure to delete this record  !!");
                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click cancle to exit!")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                 DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                                                 db.deleteContact(arg3+"");
                                                 list.remove(position);
                                                 update_page.this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                }
                                              });

                        /*  .setNegativeButton("Cancle",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                                    {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                            myintent = new Intent(update_page.this,MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(myintent);
                                        }
                                    });
                            */

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();





                    break;




                }

                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
            {
                menu.add(0,1,0,"Update Task");
                menu.add(0,2,0,"Delete");

                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            }


    }
```

Comment: thanx in advance !! and actually i want to know about how to take the position of the particular data when user click on that data.according to that i want to delete record in sqlite db.any suggestion acceptable !!